# What is the best way to access input in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, input

```js
function gener10k() {
  let x = getRndInteger(10000, 100);
  let x1 = getRndInteger(x, 10);
  let x2 = x - x1;
  let higherValue = numberToArray(x1);
  const longiness_higher = higherValue.length;
  let higherInput = document.getElementsByName("higher[]");
  for (var i = 0; i < longiness_higher; i++) {
    higherInput[i].value = higherValue[i].value;
  }
  alert('higherValue ' + x1 + ' ' + higherValue[0] + higherValue[1] + higherValue[2] + higherValue[3] + "higherInput " + higherInput[0] + higherInput[1].value + higherInput[2].value + higherInput[3].value);
}

function getRndInteger(max, min) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

function getlength(number) {
  return number.toString().length;
}

function numberToArray(number) {
  let array = number.toString().split("");
  return array.map(x => parseInt(x));
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="inputCoefs">
    <div class="inputCoef1">
      <input type="text" name="higher[]" class="coeficientsIn10000" />
      <input type="text" name="higher[]" class="coeficientsIn10000" />
      <input type="text" name="higher[]" class="coeficientsIn10000" />
      <input type="text" name="higher[]" class="coeficientsIn10000" />
      <input type="text" name="higher[]" class="coeficientsIn10000" />
    </div>
    <div class="output">
      <button class="but" id="checkit" onclick="gener10k();">DO IT</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I expected to write particular digits to equivalent input array. But instead, I have undefined variables.  What is the best way to write to input from an array?

Comment: `higherInput[i]` returns an element, not the value

Comment: higherValue does not value an array of values..... `console.log(higherInput[i].value, higherValue[i])`

Comment: And How do I access the value?

Answer (score 1):

```js
let higherInput = document.getElementsByName("higer[]");
```

This statement gets an object.

```js
let higherValue = numberToArray(x1);
```

This statement gets a number array.

In your `for` loop:

```js
higherInput[i].value = higherValue[i].value;
```

In this statement, `higherInput[i].value` refer to your text box value,
but what's `higherValue[i].value`?
Just use `higherValue[i]`.

You can use the statement below to see that `higherValue[i]` is a number.

```js
console.log(typeof(higherValue[0]);
```

Comment: It works, thanks. I just need to work out why, but this is the super lecture for me.

Comment: @user2062778 I think you may misunderstand the value property? You should use `value` to get the HTML object, but not need to use value to get a number value, number is just a value you can use, and it doesn't has a `value` property, just like you define `x`, the `x` is a number.

Comment: Yes, this is it. I did not realize it before.